# Find latest file in folder

Tags: powershell

I have the below code:a

```
$Destination = "\\DC-Server1\Backups$\Folder1"

do{
    $Server = Test-Connection 'RegionalServer1' -Count 1 -Delay 30 -Quiet    
    if($Server)
    {
        Get-ChildItem E:\Backups | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | 
        Sort-Object -Property $_.CreationTime | Select-Object -First 1 | 
        Copy-Item -Destination $Destination -Force
    }

}until($Server)
```

This script runs daily, 15 minutes after another script creates a copy at 06:00 daily. The file format is "data_$($CurrentDate).mdb"

I'm battling to find the file that was created today.

Output from `Get-ChildItem E:\Backups`

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                     
----                -------------         ------ ----                     
-a----       2021/09/01  10:46 PM      982913024 data_02-09-2021 06-00.mdb
-a----       2021/09/02   8:19 AM      982913024 data_02-09-2021 18-00.mdb
-a----       2021/09/03   1:21 AM      982913024 data_03-09-2021 06-00.mdb
-a----       2021/08/27  10:06 AM      982913024 data_27-08-2021 10-33.mdb
-a----       2021/08/27  10:40 AM      982913024 data_27-08-2021 10-45.mdb
-a----       2021/08/27   5:10 PM      982913024 data_27-08-2021 18-00.mdb
-a----       2021/08/28   5:28 AM      982913024 data_28-08-2021 06-00.mdb
-a----       2021/08/28   5:28 AM      982913024 data_28-08-2021 18-00.mdb
-a----       2021/08/29   4:24 AM      982913024 data_29-08-2021 06-00.mdb
-a----       2021/08/29   3:55 PM      982913024 data_29-08-2021 18-00.mdb
-a----       2021/08/30  12:57 AM      982913024 data_30-08-2021 06-00.mdb
-a----       2021/08/30   4:28 PM      982913024 data_30-08-2021 18-00.mdb
-a----       2021/08/30   4:28 PM      982913024 data_31-08-2021 06-00.mdb
```

Comment: You need a `-Descending` switch on that `Sort-Object` call - alternatively do `Select-Object -Last 1` (instead of `-First 1`) :-)

Comment: changed the code as suggested:
`Get-ChildItem E:\Backups | Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | Sort-Object -Property $_.Name -Descending`

results are the same

Comment: @Nuisance Nice to hear, but did it solve your problem or not?

Comment: @stackprotector no i'm battling to locate the file name when the date falls in the middle of the table.

Comment: was also thinking i could run this:
`Get-ChildItem E:\Backups | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -contains $CurrentDate }`

$CurrentDate is populated with `$CurrentDate = (Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy").ToString()` before the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking at the wrong property..
Use `.LastWriteTime` instead of `.CreationTime`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\Backups' -File | 
    Sort-Object -Property $_.LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | 
    Copy-Item -Destination $Destination -Force
```

- [LastWriteTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastwritetime) is the time the file was last modified,
  whereas
- [CreationTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime) gives you the time the file was first created. When a file gets copied or moved to another location, the CreationTime gets **altered** and takes on the date and time of when the copy was made..

<sup>Switch `-File` does the same as `Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer }`, but a lot faster. This was introduced in PowerShell version 3.0 I believe</sup>